# page-break-after does not work with the table tr in Chrome

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break, print-css

I am generating a print report using table. The table has multiple rows; While Printing the page it requires a page-break-after each 15 rows

To do so, I have applied

```
@media print {
   tr:nth-of-type(15n){
    page-break-after: always !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  }
```

**What is the issue?**

- while applying the style page-break-after to a tr , page-break is not working [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIE5g.png)
- but when applying display:block to tr , it gives desired result but the layout of table is being distorted after changing tr display:table-row to display:block [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIMv7.png) . I tried Firefox and it's ok   there.